# Power Automate Result Absolute Uri

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery, powerapps, power-automate

Hello okay? I'm having a problem I want to get some absoluteuri of some attachments in sharepoint but I wanted the power automate generates two results just to generate two photos in the html report but I was stuck in this part he only applies one photo at a time and not all the results someone knows tell me what I could do what would be the function for him to apply and generate two results??

For example in a link has two attachments I want the absolute uri of this two attachments do not know exactly how